# Is it possible to use read and write operations for NFC in the same activity in Android

Tags: android, android-activity, nfc

I am creating an application that has a main activity which is a sliding tabs navigation design. I want the activity to be constantly listening out for any NFC tag and read its information when detected. I also want that same activity to be able to switch to write mode upon user request, so that the activity will no longer listen out for an NFC tag to read and will instead write information in an asynchronous task to the NFC tag. Is this possible to do this and/or are there any problems with doing it in this way? Please can anyone help me with this situation. Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, this is possible without any complications. You would typically create a simple state machine that switches between read and write mode. Then, upon tag discovery, you would call the appropriate read or write code depending on whether you are in read or write state.

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer. That is what I wanted to hear.